# Intent ACTION_SEND doesn't show every browser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, share

I have a button which fires a ACTION_SEND intent when clicked as below:

```
private static final String WEB_URL = "https://www.google.ca/";

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, WEB_URL);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "CHOOOOOSE"));
}
```

Currently, it has some other apps, 'Copy to clipboard', and 'Add to Firefox' which can be used to open the link in Firefox. However, I want to let a user to decide which browser app to use to open the link but 'Add to Firefox' seems to be the only option right now when this device I am using has 'Chrome' and 'Internet' applications as well.

Ultimately, what I want is a share button, and on a click event, it shows all installed browser app like chrome, firefox, 'internet', etc., 'Copy to clipboard', and any other apps(<- these are not necessary, though).

Showing **all browser apps**, and a button to '**Copy to clipboard**' is what I essentially want.

The 'WEB_URL' string is always going to be a proper url.

How do I achieve this?

**EDIT**

To sum up:

I want to have a list of apps shown by 'Intent.createChooser()' whose list consist of ALL browser apps AND a 'Copy to clipboard' option.

I tried using Intent.ACTION_VIEW with intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)) but then in this case, it doesn't have the 'Copy to clipboard' option.

Comment: Your intent is to open a url or send plain text? If you want to redirect to a url you need to use Action_View along with URI in your intent.

Comment: I want to have a list of apps shown by 'Intent.createChooser()' whose list consist of ALL browser apps AND a 'Copy to clipboard' option. I tried using Intent.ACTION_VIEW with intent.setData(Uri.parse(url)) but then in this case, it doesn't have the 'Copy to clipboard' option.

Comment: I want to know what your intent is.. you either want to copy text or open a url?

Comment: My intent is to, using the given 'WEB_URL', have options shown from 'Intent.createChooser()' to show icons of brower apps, and an icon to 'Copy to clipboard'.

Yes, I want to either copy the text or open a url in a browser chosen by user. I want to have both of the abilities (copying text + open in a browser)

Comment: You cant do both in one Intent.

Comment: Oh.. are you saying there is no way to have the Intent.createChooser() to show 3 options: Chrome, FireFox, and Copy to clipboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171720/discussion-between-coderp-and-noma-citzen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

I was able to achieve what I wanted above after some research.

The key is to use 'Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS' and a custom Activity.

**SomeActivity's onClick Event**

```
private static final String WEB_URL = "https://www.google.ca/";

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(WEB_URL));

    Intent clipboardIntent = new Intent(SomeActivity.this, CopyToClipboardActivity.class);
    clipboardIntent.setData(Uri.parse(WEB_URL));

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Custom Title...");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {clipboardIntent});
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

**Add 'CopyToClipboardActivity' to Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".activities.CopyToClipboardActivity"
    android:exported="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/someIcon"
    android:label="@string/copy_to_clipboard"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"/>
```

**CopyToClipboardActivity.java**

```
public class CopyToClipboardActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            copyTextToClipboard(uri.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Link copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Finish right away. We don't want to actually display a UI.
        finish();
    }

    private void copyTextToClipboard(String url) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("URL", url);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```